# template.php check user and profile

Tags: 7, theming

I created a custom tpl file for one of my content types and I would like to check the users profile as well if they were the publisher and if it all checked out then proceed to the tpl file.

Here is an example

```
if(publisher and profile){
   proceed to tpl file
}else{
   You are not authorized to view this page.
}
```

If someone can point me in the right direction that would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not something that should be done in the theme layer. I would look at solutions like [ACL](http://drupal.org/project/acl) or [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access).

If you really need to code your own solution for some reason, [create a custom module](http://drupal.org/node/361112) and use the necessary hooks, such as [hook_permission](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7).